# SKPhysicsJointFixed doesn't keep nodes together while moving one

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I've created 2 SKSpriteNodes, and connected them by a SKPhysicsJointFixed, to keep them stuck together. The problem is when I apply a `SKAction.move(by:, duration:)` to the first, it moves alone. why is that, and how can I move them together? I've searched a lot, but can't seem to find any new or useful information. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
import SpriteKit

class myGame: SKScene {

var node1: SKSpriteNode!
var node2: SKSpriteNode!

func createNode(_ position: CGPoint, color: UIColor) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: color, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    node.position = position
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node.size, center: position)
    node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    return node
}

func setup() {
    node1 = createNode(.zero, color: .red)
    node2 = createNode(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50), color: .green)
    self.addChild(node1)
    self.addChild(node2)

    let anchor = CGPoint(x: node1.size.width/2, y: -node1.size.height/2)
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: node2.physicsBody!, anchor: anchor)
    physicsWorld.add(joint)

}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setup()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    node1.run(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100), duration: 2))
}


}
```

Comment: Try to move those by physics (forces or impulses) and see what happens...

Comment: I think it might be because you are using an SKAction to directly move the node, rather than by using physics (I.e. applying an impulse or a force to the physics body). Try changing the move to an impulse.

Comment: pretty sure the above two are correct.

Comment: @Fluidity No, I used impulse and a force, but still got the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very strange indeed, but I have encountered similar things before.
Its the AllowRotation on the physicsBody that creates the problem.

fix:

```
node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
```

Note:
your physics body for the second node is a bit off. I suggest you do like this instead:

```
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node.size)
```

And your joint is currently in the right corner of the nodes, Fix:

```
let anchor = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -node1.size.height/2)
```

unless you want it to be like that ofc :)

One last tip if you don't already know it. set showPhysics in your gameViewController to see an outline of your physics bodies. it does help a lot when working with physics.

```
view.showsPhysics = true
```

Comment: it was all about the `.allowsRotation`. Thanks alot!

Comment: If you really need to have the allowsRotation = false. you could use a distance constraint.  or simply update the position of the second node to always be next to the first.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint

Comment: but the real problem is that nodes shouldn't rotate in my app :/

Comment: Then I suggest to use a distance constraint

Comment: `let con = SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 50, upperLimit: 50), to: node1)
        node2.constraints = [ con ]`

and you can remove the joint altogether